# How to create a configuration file and use system.configuration dll in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, system.configuration

I want to use the the System.Configuration dll for my application.
So I made these actions:

1. Project > Add a new element > Add a Config file

But I couldn't find the .exe.config file in the list so I created a text file and put it in the same folder as the executable file (.exe) of my app and it worked. I could add it to my project.

2. Then I wanted to import the System.Configuration dll : Project > add a reference

And again I couldn't find the System.Configuration dll in the list so I used the NuGet install console and it worked!

```
`Install-Package System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager -Version 4.5.0`
```

**My question is**: why I can't find the Config file in my Visual C# Element Menu and I'm oblige to create a text document?

Thank you very much for your help.
Clement

Comment: For non ASP.NET projects the config file is `app.config` and is copied to the output as `name.exe.config` on build. Manually creating the latter will only lead to it being overwritten.

Comment: When I ran my app, I didn't have any .exe.config file created in the output, just my .exe file that is why I created one manually. In fact, when I want to use my manually file created .exe.config with ConfigurationManager.AppSettings it doesn't work...

Comment: Start with an `app.config` in the root of the project, and get the right output file created. Once that is done look at loading the config. (NB. this all assumes this is a .NET Framework project: .NET Core is completely different.)

Comment: I understood! I realized that I created a Console app projet with the .NET Core... So that why I didn't found the `app.config`. When I created a .NET Framework project I could find this file! Thank you very much @Richard

Comment: [This link](https://garywoodfine.com/configuration-api-net-core-console-application/) should help you: it does use the command line for project creation, but after that things are the same.